# Check FusedLocationApi for PendingIntent

Tags: android, location, google-play-services

Is there a way to check `FusedLocationApi` to see if `FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates()` has already been called with a specific `PendingIntent`?

Comment: You can try this **Request Location Updates** part of this [documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/location/receive-location-updates.html) if this is the one that you need. The fused location provider either invokes the `LocationListener.onLocationChanged()` callback method and passes it a Location object, or issues a PendingIntent that contains the location in its extended data. The accuracy and frequency of the updates are affected by the location permissions you've requested and the options you set in the location request object. Just check the docu page for the sample code.